# Objective-C: проверка наличия файла

Tags: ios, objective-c, link

Загружаю `zip` файл в папку в моем приложении. Наблюдаю за прогрессом загрузки от 1% до 100% в моем `label`. После того, как `label` = 100% я не нахожу файл в папке. Он появляется спустя 50 секунд. Как я могу постоянно проверять наличие файла в течение 50 секунд, чтобы точно знать кода он появится в папке?

код загрузки

```
-(IBAction) downloadButton:(id)sender
{
    if (_HighScore == 2) {

        _url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"link2.zip"];

        _downloadTask1 = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url1];

        [_downloadTask1 resume];
}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{

    if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {
        _documentsDirectory1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        _zipPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.zip"];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) { NSData *urlData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url1]; [urlData1 writeToFile:_zipPath1 atomically:YES];}

});
}
```

**UPD**

```
_documentsDirectory1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    _zipPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.zip"];
    _destinationPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MediaData"];
    _fileExists1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_zipPath1 isDirectory:false];
    if( [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:_zipPath1 toDestination:_destinationPath1] != NO ) {
        NSLog(@"Dilip Success");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Dilip Error");
    }
```

Comment: как так появляется через 50 секунд? а что он делает после окончания загрузки и до появления?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Не знаю. Просто после 100% я засек время через которое вижу его в папке. Предполагалось, что после того как label = 100% вызывается окончание загрузки. Время после окончания загрузки можно сократить?

Comment: после окончания загрузки файл должен быть доступен мгновенно. что то у вас там не так. можете собрать пример проекта и выложить

Comment: стоять. так вы ж два раза сохраняете. сначала при помощи downloadTaskWithUrl, а когда он выполнился, вы запускаете dataWithContentsOfURL и скачиваете его еще раз.

Comment: у вас в didFinishDownloadingToUrl приходит location. там файл и должен лежать

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Можете показать как должен выглядеть код? что-то не разберусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как уже написал в комментарии, у вас скачивание происходит два раза - первый вы скачиваете через NSSession, и когда он закончил скачивать и выполнил

```
- (void)URLSession: downloadTask: didFinishDownloadingToURL:
```

вы скачиваете еще раз используя

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url1]
```

Что вам надо делать, в `didFinishDownloadingToURL` просто смотреть куда файл скачан и его оттуда брать. типа такого:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSURL *documentsFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/myCoolFile.txt", documentsFolder]];

    NSError *error;
    [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:newLocation error:&error];

}
```

Comment: Если перейду в папку по пути `NSLog(@«вот файл %@«, location.absoluteString);` там будет только tmp файл. моего zip там нет. Так и должно быть?

Comment: вот что говорит нам документация: A file URL for the temporary file. Because the file is temporary, you must either open the file for reading or move it to a permanent location in your app’s sandbox container directory before returning from this delegate method.

If you choose to open the file for reading, you should do the actual reading in another thread to avoid blocking the delegate queue.

Comment: другими словами, вам надо его скопировать в папку своего приложения

Comment: Как это сделать в коде? можете показать, пожалуйста? нигде не нашел как это можно сделать

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Чтобы разархивировать файл или получить к нему доступ я должен пройти по этому пути NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@«%@/myCoolFile.txt", documentsFolder]]; ?

Comment: путь и имя файла сделайте какое вам нравится. но в целом да - файл скачивается во временную папку и потом вы его переносите куда хотите

Comment: после загрузки файл копируется в `newLocation` но я добавляю в код  `NSLog(@«вот файл %@«, newLocation.absoluteString);` чтобы убедится в этом и по этому пути не нахожу файл. После загрузки мне нужно разархивировать файл(код добавил в вопрос), и вместо `_destinationPath1` нужно указать путь. Но я не знаю какой путь указать т.к нигде не могу найти файл.

Comment: исправил ответ - добавил file:// протокол